# Informative Alert is Still Showing on Scan Result

Tags: azure-devops, owasp

I have a pipeline which contains a task to scan our website for vulnerabilities. The -l parameter (level) has been set to FAIL, but when I ran the scan I still received an alert for [Alert 10049-2](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/10049-2/). This alert is only Informative so I was expecting it not to show up in the result.

- bash: |
  chmod -R 777 ./
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://app.azurewebsites.net -l FAIL -s -x zap-report.xml -r zap-report.html -J zap-report-be.json
  true
  displayName: 'Run OWASP Zap'

Can you help me on this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-l` flag only affects the failure code. If you want to change which alerts shown to you then you need to supply a config file as per the docs.

Comment: Is it possible to create and point to this file inside the same folder as the yaml file? Or should I deploy it in a location accessible via the public internet?

Comment: Which yaml file?

Comment: If the folder location of our project is /app/src, can we create the config file in /app/src/owasp? Can we point the -c parameter to a folder location instead of a URL?

Comment: It needs to be under the directory you run the docker command in. But you need to specify the path as it will appear in docker. so if your cwd is `/user/me/app/src` and the file is `/user/me/app/src/owasp/config.conf` then you need to specify it as it will appear in docker: `/zap/wrk/owasp/config.conf`